# Ошибка структуры предложения?

Tags: сказуемые

Порой я встречаю предложения со структурой, подобной этой:

**Они не признают условностей, а лишь эффективность.**

Во второй части предложения выпущено слово 'признают', которое должно восстанавливаться из первой части.
Но в первой части глагол использован с отрицанием, и у меня стойкое ощущение, что восстанавливаться он должен тоже с отрицанием. А если во второй части отрицание не подразумевается, то глагол надо повторить:

**Они не признают условностей, а признают лишь эффективность.**

Мне кажется, первоначальная структура — это грамматически ошибочная склейка моего варианта (с повтором глагола) и варианта со структурой 'не... а...':

**Они признают не условности, а лишь эффективность.**

Я прав?

Comment: Я думаю так. Ваши варианты выглядят корректными,  а первое предложение  построено неверно (что определяется даже на слух).  Это именно  необоснованное соединение разных структур. А что, часто такое встречается?

Comment: @Sharon встречается. Этот вот случай у Емца выцепил.

Comment: Тогда надо где-то в источниках искать доказательства того, что такой вариант допускается и где допускается В разговорном стиле, например. Я бы написала так: Они не признают условностей – им нужна эффективность.

Comment: @Sharon я думаю, он не допускается, просто редактор не заметил.

Comment: Может быть, и так, это все-таки книжный текст. А в разговорной речи вроде бы допускается – ну, пропущено слово "признают", делов-то..  И разговорный вариант постепенно становится привычным для слуха и в конце концов как-то закрепляется в языке.

Comment: @Sharon не люблю я, когда безграмотность становится 'разговорным вариантом'. Лично я не стану использовать 'одеть' в значении 'надеть', или 'должен' в значении 'обязан', или вот так косячить, как в данном примере.

Comment: А здесь вы вообще ничего не докажете, пока у Розенталя или еще где не найдете. У вас ведь только "ощущение", а вам  же скажут, что нужный глагол здесь подразумевается. А какой глагол – это ясно видно из текста.

Comment: @Sharon мне кажется, тут дело не в глаголе как глаголе, а глаголе с отрицанием как сказуемом.

Comment: Мне тоже так кажется, да только  "кажется" –  это не доказательство. А со временем и вам перестанет "казаться" :)